# Understanding terminologies on Esri ArcSDE

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, replication, archiving

I am new to ArcSDE.

Can anyone help me understand the differences between versioning, replication, synchronization, archiving, editor tracking, and schema change?

Their concepts are similar to me.

Here are more specific questions, but you don't have to stick with answering all of these questions as I just want to understand the differences:

1) What I know is, by enabling archiving, all edits will be saved. [Editor tracking](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/about-tracking-an-editor-s-changes-to-data.htm) allows you to see all edits. Then, why do you need both? What are the differences between [archiving](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/the-archive-process.htm) and editor tracking?

2) Is [versioning](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/an-overview-of-versioning.htm) only enable after enabling archiving or [replication](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/working-with-geodatabase-replication.htm)?

3) Is versioning like auto-save in Microsoft program? As Microsoft programs have an auto save function, you can access the file--choosing one among the various versions by saving time--when the file is suddenly closed without saving. In that case, the versioning is temporary process?

4) I get [synchronization](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/what-is-synchronization.htm) is matching a version of a file between SDEDev and SDEPub. But there are versioning and replication.. why do you need the synchronization?

5) I was told that a new replica is better to be created after schema changes. Then why do you need versioning and editor tracking?

I think I am really confused.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Thank you for taking the [tour]. This site is a little different from other sites in that it is focused on one question per question - it's not a discussion forum. Your question covers a number of related (and individually complex) topics. Please [edit] your question to focus on one answerable question.

Comment: Since you're starting fresh, your best bet is to drop "ArcSDE" from consideration. All that's left of was once ArcSDE is a connection file with a .sde suffix. All of the different features to which you refer are properties of an Enterprise geodatabase. All of them are quite discrete, with little overlap (for example, Editor Tracking adds a user and change date during edits, but does not have anything else to do with the editing models). If you have a pair of specific concepts to declutter, then please focus the question on that.

Comment: I started to write a direct response to each question, but I don't think that will help you in the long run. Visit https://www.esri.com/training/ and work through some of the free geodatabase modules. They have a 'Getting Started with the Geodatabase' course that is free and <4 hours long. If your organization support it, I would 100% recommend attending an online geodatabase training course. You'll learn more in 2 days that you will in weeks reading the various technical docs.

Comment: this a good set of questions, but it's too broad for our one question format.  i would follow Radar's advice and take a training course on databases.  You are also welcome to split this question into the 5 individual questions you've listed and post them to the site as 5 different questions.

Comment: I really appreciate all of your answers. I will try to access the ESRI Training to understand, and will get back to these questions!